# C -Memory allocation for a structure

Tags: c, memory-management, structure

Suppose I have the following structure definition:-

```
struct structure
  {
   int a;
   int array[];
  }one;
```

How is the memory allocated  for the above structure when the array size is unsepicified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming 32-bit `int` and 8-bit `char`, `sizeof one` is likely `4`.  That is, `array` is an empty (zero-length) array.  Normally you'd dynamically allocate a structure with a flexible array member:

```
struct structure *two = malloc(sizeof *two + 32 * sizeof(int));
```

Which makes `two` a pointer to a `struct structure` with 32 elements in its `array` field.

Comment: +1, Note regarding *flexible array*: C99 §6.7.2.1-18, "... the size of the structure is as if the flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than the omission would imply."